# I am trying to incorporate login with google on website but getting error

Tags: google-signin, google-people-api

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Google_Service_Exception

Message: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?fields=id%2Cgender%2Cname%2Cimage%2CplacesLived: (403) Legacy People API has not been used in project 155462237002 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=155462237002 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Filename: /home/profism/public_html/myaccount/application/libraries/Google/Http/REST.php

I have already enabled **Google People API** . still Its not fetching data for me.

Comment: Have you done this: 'If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.'?

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the deprecated **G+ People API** which is **NOT** the **Google People API**. Please follow the documentation at https://developers.google.com/people for how to query the People API.